# How to process XML returned after submitting a form?

Tags: php, xml, submit, form-submit

I have just started a project that involves me sending data using POST in HTML forms to a another companies server. This returns XML. I need to process this XML to display certain information on a web page.

I am using PHP and have no idea where to start with how to access the XML. Once I knwo how to get at it I know how to access it using XPath.

Any tips of how to get started or links to sites with information on this would be very useful.

Comment: Is this AJAX or synchronous? And are users POSTing the form to your server, and then you POST it to the 3rd-party server and relay the results to the user, or are users POSTing the form directly to the 3rd-party server (e.g. via AJAX)?

Comment: It is asynchronous. Users will post from my server to the 3rd party server. The results then come back as XML, which currently is displayed in the browser. However I want to process this using PHP so I can save certain elements to a DB and display others to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the DOMDocument() class, it comes as part of the standard PHP installation on most systems.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

ohhh, I see.  You should set up a PHP script that the user form posts to.  If you want to process the XML response you should then pass those fields on to the remote server using cURL.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

A simple example would be something like:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://the_remote_server");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
$YourXMLResponse = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to set up the parser using DOMDocument() or SimpleXML, but when I post the data how do I get the XML that is returned to put into the DOMDocument or simpleXML.

Comment: Thats great, exactly what I was after. Thanks